# MySQL inserts values into wrong columns

Tags: php, mysql

**Problem**

With a php website, I have a form to collect information which will then be inserted into the MySQL database, but there are these three columns that have the wrong values inserted into them. The rest are all in the correct order.

Values inserted as php variables via MySQL transaction.

Thank you for your time.

[phpmyadmin display (first row is manually corrected)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSZvY.png)

**Code:**

```
 <?php
function registerPatient($ptUsername, $ptPassword, $ptFirstName, $ptLastName, $ptSalutation, $ptEmail, $ptDOB, $ptPostCode, $ptHouseNo, $ptTelNo, $link)
{
    $accType = "Patient";
    $dtID = $_COOKIE["ID"];
    $errors = "";
    $SQL_patientInsert =

        "START TRANSACTION;

        INSERT INTO accDetails (`username`, `hashPassword`, `accType`)
        VALUES ('" . $ptUsername . "',
                '" . $ptPassword . "',
                '" . $accType . "');


        INSERT INTO ptProfile (`firstName`, `lastName`, `salutation`, `email`, `DOB`, `postCode`, `houseNo`, `telephoneNo`, `dtID`, `ptID`)
        VALUES ('" . $ptFirstName . "',
                '" . $ptLastName . "',
                '" . $ptSalutation . "',
                '" . $ptEmail . "',
                '" . $ptDOB . "',
                '" . $ptPostCode . "',
                '" . $ptHouseNo . "',
                '" . $ptTelNo . "',
                '" . $dtID . "',
                LAST_INSERT_ID());
        COMMIT;";

        if (mysqli_multi_query($link, $SQL_patientInsert)) {
            $errors .= "";
        } else {
            $errors .= "MYSQL Error: ". mysqli_error($link);
        }


        return $errors;

    }

?>
```

**Var_Dump of $SQL_patientInsert**

```
string(495) "START TRANSACTION; INSERT INTO accDetails (`username`, `hashPassword`, `accType`) VALUES ('bingbong', '$2y$10$WDvSHSxzIxaYB8dPGLRIWOFyIdPXxSw5JDXagOxeYuJUtnvFhI.lO', 'Patient'); INSERT INTO ptProfile (`firstName`, `lastName`, `salutation`, `email`, `DOB`, `postCode`, `houseNo`, `telephoneNo`, `dtID`, `ptID`) VALUES ('Dr', 'Bing', 'Bong', 'EMAIL REMOVED FOR SO', '1996-08-02', 'POSTCODE REMOVED FOR SO', '7', '83824', '1256', LAST_INSERT_ID()); COMMIT;"
```

**Table Structure**

[Table Structure in PHPMyAdmin, no autoincrements, all values allowed to be null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usCk3.png)

Comment: Warning! You are prone to SQL-injection. Read more here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: var_dump your $SQL_patientInsert, i'm pretty sure you have an error in varaible maybe order in registerPatient call

Comment: Have you setup your table data types of column properly and auto increment value etc

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/guSN6LL) Doesn't appear to show anything incorrect with the variables, that's the vardump of $SQL_patientinsert right after insertion.

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/tg7ZPGk) - No autoincrements. All values allowed to be null. Can't see any issues with my column datatypes. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, really strange. Did you try to insert just 3 columns *`firstName`, `lastName`, `salutation`* ?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are calling your function with wrong parameters order.

Change this line ($ptFirstName <-> $ptSalutation);

```
function registerPatient($ptUsername, $ptPassword, $ptFirstName, $ptLastName, $ptSalutation, $ptEmail, $ptDOB, $ptPostCode, $ptHouseNo, $ptTelNo, $link)
```

with

```
function registerPatient($ptUsername, $ptPassword, $ptSalutation, $ptFirstName, $ptLastName, $ptEmail, $ptDOB, $ptPostCode, $ptHouseNo, $ptTelNo, $link)
```

Comment: When you have this many arguments, passing them all in as a singular `array` is not a bad idea.

Comment: That's fixed it. Thank you very much, it's well appreciated. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just mixed up your variables somewhere. Have you checked the form? Try printing out all the variables right before you build the query and check if they correspond correctly.

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/guSN6LL) Doesn't appear to show anything incorrect with the variables, that's the vardump of $SQL_patientinsert right after insertion, same occurs with vardump before query is run.